# Multiple File Upload jquery ajax with extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have problem in uploading multiple file upload using jquery/ajax.

my problem is when i try to submit a file with png or jpg file it didnt even submit and it will alert Please Upload file even though i have put a file.

what should i do in order to go in my else statement. coz i tried to remove my condition i just put the ajax and it works and put to my database. but when i put a condition with a proper file extension even if i have put jpg or png file still it will alert please upload file.

here is my CODE

HTML

```
 <!-- MULTIPLE UPLOAD FORM -->
 <h1>Multiple File Upload</h1>
<form id="multiple" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple />
    <input type="submit" id="multBtn" value="Upload File">
    </br>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$("#multBtn").on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var imgData = document.getElementsByName('file')[0]; 
var imageUploadPath = imgData.value;

if(imageUploadPath == ''){ // user did not upload anything
    alert('Please Upload File');
}
else{
    //user uploaded a file
    var Extension = imageUploadPath.substring(imageUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();
    if(Extension == "png" || Extension == "Jpeg" || Extension == "jpg"){
        $.ajax({
        url: '/uploadMultipleImg',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){

        },
        });
        return false;
    }   }
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see where things go wrong? For example, what value does `Extension` have?

Comment: Also you are casting the return of substring to `lowerCase `but you are checking `"Jpeg"` at your if statement.

Comment: @Pekka웃 before i tried to put the variable extension. i just tried first the ajax without any conditions and variable Extension given and its working. and it goes to my database, then i tried the code of my single file uploading and apply it to my multiple file upload. when i tried to alert the variable imageUploadPath it doesn't have value and i dont know why it didnt read the file i put. and i didnt pass to my else statement

Comment: @A.OzanEkici the problem is even i have insert a image it doesn't even go to my else statement. it just go to my if statement. if(imageUploadPath == ''){ // user did not upload anything
  alert('Please Upload File');
 }

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('file')[0]` – there is no element with the name `file` in your form.

Comment: @CBroe what should i do to get the value of my of file[] <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple />

Comment: Select the element by its actual name ...?

Comment: @CBroe i think i already did that in the code ive showed? var imgData = document.getElementsByName('file')[0]; 
or there is something wrong there?

Comment: I already told you: There is no field with the name `file` in your form.

Comment: @CBroe  <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple /> this is my field in my form

Comment: And what name does that field have …?

Answer (score 0):

To check if the file is selected use:

```
var fileUpload = $("#file").get(0);
var files = fileUpload.files;
```

Then loop through the files like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    //code
}
```

Change your file input name and make it same as id.

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple />
```

You can see [this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2015/05/jquery-upload-multiple-files-in-aspnet-using-handler-file-in-csharp-vbnet.html) tutorial on file upload with ajax which will help.